# How should I write a sentence that has multiple questions?

Tags: questions, formality, grammar-myths, lists

I got these words from a speech, so I'm not entirely sure how I would write this...

> Is the website easy to navigate? Easy-to-read? Well-structured? Concise?

"Easy-to-read" and the others are fragments, aren't they? So the above sentences are incorrect?

Comment: They might technically be fragments, but the whole thing is easy to understand and it sounds better than `Is the website easy to navigate? Is the website easy-to-read? Is the website well-structured? Is the website Ccncise?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing really *incorrect* in your example.
People use that form all the time in different circumstances.

> How was your vacation? Interesting? Fun? Good weather?
>   What's she like? Tall? Thin? Funny?

It's easier to use if one has a list of *things* one is wondering about.

Comment: Can you please explain more about the list of things you mentioned?